# Unable to resolve module `buffer` from react-native-ssdp

Tags: react-native

I am facing unable to resolve module 'buffer' from react-native-ssdp.Any one knows how to fix this issue. React native version
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.58.5/0.59.8

I have tried
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

Comment: same here, did you ever ding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So, after digging into the component, I found that `buffer` and other components required by the package are under the peer dependency section of the package.json file.
This means they will not be installed locally for the package, but rather depend on what is installed in your main package.

The quickest fix was installing these packages which are required by the package.
Note that there are several such packages out there that have probably the same exact code such as `react-native-ssdp`, `react-native-ssdp-grok` and `react-native-upnp`.
The same solution will work for any of them.

Install these:
`react-native-udp`, `buffer`, and `react-native-network-info`.

Check the module's package.json for the specific requirements.